# Python with Protobuf in Docker "TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!"

Tags: python, docker, protocol-buffers

I have a python app that uses protocol buffers. I am trying to get it running in Docker, but it is throwing an error when I execute `docker run`:

Here are the Dockerfile contents:

```
 FROM python:3.5-onbuild
 CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

Here is the error:

```
bash-3.2$ docker run gcr.io/skroot-com/geo-boundary-refiner:0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from skroot.schema.pipeline.event import geo_boundary_marked_pb2
  File "/usr/src/app/skroot/schema/pipeline/event/geo_boundary_marked_pb2.py", line 18, in <module>
    from skroot.schema.pipeline import image_info_pb2 as skroot_dot_schema_dot_pipeline_dot_image__info__pb2
  File "/usr/src/app/skroot/schema/pipeline/image_info_pb2.py", line 26, in <module>
    dependencies=[skroot_dot_schema_dot_pipeline_dot_cloud__storage__location__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,skroot_dot_schema_dot_pipeline_dot___matrix__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 829, in __new__
    return _message.default_pool.AddSerializedFile(serialized_pb)
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "image_info.proto":
  image_info.proto: Import "skroot/schema/pipeline/cloud_storage_location.proto" has not been loaded.
  image_info.proto: Import "skroot/schema/pipeline/matrix.proto" has not been loaded.
  skroot.schema.pipeline.ImageInfo.Image.location: "skroot.schema.pipeline.CloudStorageLocation" seems to be defined in "cloud_storage_location.proto", which is not imported by "image_info.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  skroot.schema.pipeline.ImageInfo.TranscodedImage.matrix: "skroot.schema.pipeline.Matrix" seems to be defined in "matrix.proto", which is not imported by "image_info.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

In the `image_info.proto` file, the .proto files it is complaining about are imported:

```
import "skroot/schema/pipeline/cloud_storage_location.proto";
import "skroot/schema/pipeline/matrix.proto";
```

The generated protobuf files are in the `skroot/schema/pipeline/` directory.

I'm perplexed because this runs locally. It is only when I try to run it in Docker that I get these errors.

Comment: I was trying to build your Dockerfile but for some reason it throws an error when I'm building the image. The error says `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder337956465/requirements.txt: no such file or directory`